# No handler for message

Tags: php, symfony, messaging, symfony6

Can anyone help and tell me why this handler (CalculateFeeCommandHandler) is not visible and I get this error? The code is written in Symfony 6.

[image]

Dispatching message:

[image]

And messenger configuration:

[image]

Command looks like this:

[image]

In addition, after typing in the command as you would expect I do not see my handler:

[image]

I followed this instruction: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html

Comment: Please don't post code and logs as images but use code tags ``` instead

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See also [ask].

Comment: Did you tag `CalculateFeeCommandHandler` with `messenger.message_handler`? Does it implement `Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageSubscriberInterface`?
BTW. your messenger configuration has inconsistent indentation - sometimes it's 4 spaces, sometimes 2. It's probably unrelated, but you might wanna fix that.

Comment: You can use as well AsMessageHandler attribute as in example in documentation